# Dynamically specify a property on a model using razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, razor

I have a razor view with model object that is a collection of items that have two language properties, one for English and one for French. I am looking for a way to dynamically reference the correct language property in a razor view.

I can do this:

```
if (Culture == "en-CA")
    return model.English;
else
    return model.French;
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
if (Culture == "en-CA")
    lang = "English"
else
    lang = "French"

...

@foreach (var record in Model) {
    @record.lang
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Razor syntax just gives you an easy way to write C# or VB.NET in your views... but you are still using static language.  To answer your question with a question:  how would you accomplish the same thing outside of Razor?  e.g. what code would you write in order to render the same thing to the console?

I don't know what your classes actually look like, but if you say they are dictionaries then you could just do:

```
@foreach(var in record in Model) {
    @record[lang]
}
```

just like any normal dictionary.